# Getting a list of curly brace blocks using regex

Tags: c++, regex

I'm building a simple data encoder/decoder for a project I'm doing in c++, the data is written to a file in this format (dummy data):

```
{X143Y453CGRjGeBK}{X243Y6789CaRyGwBk}{X5743Y12CvRYGQBs}
```

The number of blocks is indefinite and the size of the blocks is variable.

To decode the image I need to iterate through each curly brace block and process the data within, the ideal output would look like this:

```
"X143Y453CGRjGeBK" "X243Y6789CaRyGwBk" "X5743Y12CvRYGQBs"
```

The closest I've got is:

```
"\\{(.*)\\}"
```

But this gives me the whole sequence rather than each block.

Sorry if this is a simple problem but regex hasn't really clicked with me yet, is this possible with regex or should I use a different method?

Comment: Using **[^{}]+** looks like working https://regex101.com/r/bNOK5U/1, if it works, i can post it as an answer

Comment: Yes that works perfectly thanks a lot! post it and I'll mark it

Comment: `[^{}]+` will fail if a string like `Text here {X143Y453CGRjGeBK} and here {X243Y6789CaRyGwBk}{X5743Y12CvRYGQBs} and more here.`

Comment: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52800614/3832970) that will work in a more general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[^{}]+`:

- `[^{}]`: Match a single character not present in the list below (in this case `'{' & '}'`)
- `\+`: once you match that character, match one and unlimited times as many as possible.

Testing: https://regex101.com/r/bNOK5U/1/

Answer (score 1):

To extract multiple occurrences of substrings inside curly braces, that have no braces inside (that is, substrings inside innermost braces), you may use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::regex rx(R"(\{([^{}]*)})");
    std::string s = "Text here {X143Y453CGRjGeBK} and here {X243Y6789CaRyGwBk}{X5743Y12CvRYGQBs} and more here.";
    std::vector<std::string> results(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), rx, 1),
                               std::sregex_token_iterator());

    for( auto & p : results ) std::cout << p << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

See a [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/W7ijtM).

The `std::regex rx(R"(\{([^{}]*)})")` regex string is [`\{([^{}]*)}`](https://regex101.com/r/FuwXhG/1), and it matches

- `\{` - a `{` char
- `([^{}]*)` - Capturing group 1: zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.

The `1` argument passed to the `std::sregex_token_iterator` extracts just thiose values that are captured into Group 1.

Comment: This is very useful, however, because I control the encoding scheme there should never be text between the brackets in my case, so I'll keep the simpler solution